# Почему foreach не срабатывает ?

Tags: post, php, html, key, foreach

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['adles']))  {
echo "hello it is addlesname";
            $groupp=$_POST['group'];
            #для группы
                                    foreach($groupp as $key=>$value)    {
                                        echo $value.$key.'<br>';    }

            echo "$groupp[0]".'<br>';
            print_r($groupp);

                }

?>
```

выводит

> hello it is addlesname
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
> C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\a\addlesname.php
> on line 9
>
> Array ( [6031к] => )

Comment: А что такое `$groupp[0]`? И, кстати, что Вы ожидаете увидеть из своего foreach -- один дополнительный перевод строки?

Comment: массив так сказать содержит 1 элемент
в print_r это видно...и тут вопрос почему этому единственному элементу не может быть присвоен ключ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас 1 элемент с пустым значением, т.е.  у вас

```
$groupp=array( '6031к' => ' ' );
foreach($groupp as $key=>$value)echo $value.'<br>';
```

и выводить нечего. А в случае

```
foreach($groupp as $key=>$value) echo $key.'<br>';
```

уже выведет ключ.